# Trouble creating war file with Ant using Eclipse and Tomcat 7 server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant, war

I am writing an Ant buildfile to create my first war file using Eclipse and Tomcat 7 server.  This is my first time creating a war file.  I have gotten the build file to create a war file, but when I unzip the war file, I find that it does not contain everything that it needs to contain.

As a result, when I try to deploy the application to tomcat in the form of the war file, the web container cannot find any of the servlets in the application.  I am posting my inputs, outputs, and code below.  How can I fix the code below so that the outputs in the war file match the inputs from Eclipse?

Here is the structure of the Eclipse project:

[image]

Here are the contents of the unzipped war file:

[image]

And here is the code for the Ant buildfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project basedir="C:\mypath\workspace\myapp" name="myapp" default="default">
    <target name="default" depends="setup,compile,buildwar,deploy"></target>

    <target name="setup">
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
        <echo>Copying web into dist</echo>
        <copydir dest="dist/web" src="web" />
        <copydir dest="dist/web/WEB-INF/lib" src="${basedir}/web/WEB-INF/lib" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <javac destdir="${dist.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes" srcdir="src">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${basedir}/web/WEB-INF/lib">
                    <include name="*" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${dist.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <include name="**/*.properties" />
                <include name="**/*.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="buildwar">
        <war basedir="${basedir}/dist/web" destfile="myapp.war"
             webxml="${basedir}/dist/web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
            <webinf dir="${basedir}/dist/web/WEB-INF/">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </webinf>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
        <copy file="myapp.war" todir="${tomcat.deploydir}" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Please note that running this script creates three copies of the war file. I only want one copy.

### Edit

I tried Shaunak's suggestion, and am getting the following output now when I unzip the war file:

[image]

Deploying the resulting war to Tomcat still produces 404 errors because the web container cannot find the servlets.  I cannot seem to find web.xml or myapp.xml in the output, and none of the jar file dependencies seem to be present in the war file either, but the good news is that the package folders seem to contain both Java files and class files.

### Second edit

Here is the Ant build file that Eclipse generated.  Where is the .war file that is supposed to be created when the following build file is run? And what is the name of the war file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
          Any modifications will be overwritten.
          To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
          directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
          as the first entry and export the buildfile again. --><project basedir="." default="build" name="myapp">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../../../java/eclipse"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.7"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.7"/>
    <path id="Web App Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
    <path id="EAR Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
    <path id="myapp.classpath">
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/ant.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/jaxen.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/xerces.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-1.1.3-javadoc.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-1.1.3-sources.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-1.1.3-test-sources.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-adapters-1.1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-tests.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3-javadoc.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3-sources.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3-test-sources.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-adapters-1.1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-tests.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/lib/jsp-api.jar"/>
        <path refid="Web App Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
        <path refid="EAR Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="web/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="web/WEB-INF/classes">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="web/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="web/WEB-INF/classes" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="myapp.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="GetBI">
        <java classname="myapp.plotters.GetBI" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="myapp.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>
    <target name="GetPlotGIF (2)">
        <java classname="myapp.plotters.GetPlotGIF" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="myapp.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Eclipse generates a ant build file for you automatically. Did you try using it? Its usually a good stable starting point which you can start modifying. Right click your project --> export --> type Ant --> export. This will work even better if you already have tomcat or other server already setup in eclipse and eclipse is able to deploy it there.

Comment: @Shaunak Thank you.  I tried your method and posted the results in an edit to my original posting above.  Are you using a plugin?  I am using eclipse Juno release 1.  Right clicking the project folder and choosing export gives a war option, but not an ant option.  I chose the war option and got the results reported in my edit.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: yes i use juno. when you select export, in the text input type ant and press enter. It should give you Ant option. Let me know if it doesn't then we can debug it further

Comment: @Shaunak Thanks.  I found the ant option, and it enables eclipse to create a 200+ line ant build file.  But when I run the ant file, I cannot find the resulting war file.  Typing myapp.war into the windows start menu produces no results.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think by default it puts the war file into your web server. you will have to check the path of where your server is configured in eclipse.

Comment: @Shaunak Thanks.  I looked in the tomcat7/webapps folder, and cannot find myapp.war . Any suggestions of where else to look?

Comment: nope sorry, unless I can look at the war file eclipse generated. I would suggest take bits and pieces from it that you need, specific targets, and use them in your original ant file.

Comment: @Shaunak I just posted the ant build file that eclipse created as an edit to my original posting above.  Can you tell from it where the war file is located?  And what the name of the war file is?

Comment: I've tidied this post up, but with no answers, and all the images broken, I wonder if this ought to be put on hold for now. (This common issue is why posts should only use the Stack Overflow CDN).